# Find and Replace Number Names with Digits

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I have a long section of code that has number names, which I'd like to replace with just number symbols.

What I have:

```
PartOne
PartTwo
PartThree
PartFour
PartFive
...
PartOneHundred
```

What I want:

```
Part1
Part2
Part3
Part4
Part5
...
Part100
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in Notepad++ or similar? It'd be very time consuming to replace them all by hand. This seems like it should be an easy task, but I can't find any such result in my searches.

Comment: What would PartOneHundredAndOne be? I assume 101,but do you have "and" in your strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly in Notepad++, I doubt it.  Converting text to a numeral has a lot of logic, and even super-fancy regex probably aren't up for the task.

If they really are sequential (like your example) and really are contiguous (like your example), I would probably just rebuild it in my favorite spreadsheet, then copy/paste from ColumnB into Notepad++:

```
# | ColumnA  | ColumnB
1 | =row()   | ="Part"&A1
2 | =row()   | ="Part"&A2
...
```

If you're willing to use a scripting language, Perl has [Lingua::EN::Words2Nums](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Words2Nums) module to help make your life easier

```
cat source.txt | perl -MLingua::EN::Words2Nums -e "while (<>) { if(/^Part/) { s/^Part//; print 'Part' . words2nums($_) . qq{\n}; } else { print $_; }; } " > destination.txt
```

This script includes the feature that lines beginning with "Part" will be converted to numeric, whereas lines that don't will just pass straight thru.  For example, adding a couple lines to your example, I got the following output from my script:

```
Part1
ignore
Part2
Part3
Part4
keep in place
Part5
Part100
okay
```

It wouldn't surprise me if Python has a similar module (or whatever Python calls its equivalent of Perl modules).  If you are more comfortable with Python, I would go that route, because then you could build directly into Notepad++ using the PythonScript module, and not have to do the File-IO in the script.

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was finding and replacing the text "twenty" to 2, "thirty" to 3, and then "three" to 3 and "four" to 4 and so on, and correcting any errors that left behind such as with 10-19 manually. This is also a possible solution.